# String present in Data Table or not in c#

Tags: c#

I want to find the specific string in specific column of data table so that it is present or not in all rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;

string columnName = "SomeColumnName;"
string matchPattern = "matchPattern";

// returns rows which contains pattern in specific columns
var result = tbl.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(f => f.Field<string>(columnName))
                .Where(c => c.Contains(matchPattern));


// returns true if all rows contains pattern in specific column
var result = tbl.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(f => f.Field<string>(columnName))
                .All(c => c.Contains(matchPattern));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Checks whether all rows contain "data" in the column "colName"
var b1 = table.AsEnumerable().All(dr => dr["colName"].ToString().Contains("data"));

// Checks whether all rows equals "data" in the column "colName"
var b2 = table.AsEnumerable().All(dr => dr["colName"].ToString() == "data");

// Checks whether all employees have a last name containing "ab"
var b3 = table.AsEnumerable().All(dr => ((FullName)dr["fullName"]).Last.Contains("ab"));
```